# Mollifiers: Approximation

Tags: calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Problem**

Given a mollifier: $\varphi\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$

> Then it acts as an approximate identity:
>   $$f\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}):\quad\int_{-\infty}^\infty n\varphi(nx)f(x)dx\to f(0)\cdot\int_{-\infty}^\infty\varphi(x)dx$$
>   How to prove this under reasonable assumptions?

**Example**

As an example regard the Gaussian:
$$f\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}):\quad\frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(nx)^2}f(x)\mathrm{d}x\to f(0)$$
*(This is a useful technique when studying operator semigroups.)*

Comment: It's not true, you need special $\mu$ for that. Consider $\mu = \delta_1$, the unit mass in $1$. Then $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty n j(nx)f(x)\,d\mu(x) = n j(n)f(1),$$ and that has no reason to converge to $f(0)\cdot j(1)$.

Comment: Ok let me narrow my question, if you don't mind?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: Ok I think that is my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Now, I got a proof for the case...*

**Theorem**

Given a mollifier: $\varphi\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$

> For bounded functions one has:
> $$f\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}):\quad\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}n\varphi(nx)f(x)\mathrm{d}x\to f(0)\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x)\mathrm{d}x\quad(\|f\|_\infty<\infty)$$
> *(In fact, this result extends to the Bochner integral!)*

**Proof**

Split the integral into outer vanishing parts and the inner convergent part:
$$\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(\hat{x})f(\tfrac{1}{n}\hat{x})\mathrm{d}\hat{x}-f(0)\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(\hat{x})\mathrm{d}\hat{x}\right|\\\leq\int_{-\infty}^{-R}|\varphi(\hat{x})|\cdot2\|f\|_\infty\mathrm{d}\hat{x}+\int_{-R}^{R}\|\varphi\|_\infty\cdot\left|f\left(\tfrac{1}{n}\hat{x}\right)-f(0)\right|\mathrm{d}\hat{x}+\int_{R}^{\infty}|\varphi(\hat{x})|\cdot2\|f\|_\infty\mathrm{d}\hat{x}\\\leq2\|f\|_\infty\delta_R+\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)\delta_N+2\|f\|_\infty\delta_R=\varepsilon\quad(n\geq N_R(\varepsilon))$$
That proves the assertion.

**Outview**

Does it apply to unbounded functions too:
$$f\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}):\quad\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}n\varphi(nx)f(x)\mathrm{d}x\to f(0)\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
*(Intuition and examples suggest it does.)*

Answer (score 0):

You can always approximate $j(x)$ by bounded continuous functions, for which the result holds by dominated convergence and the usual *Riemann*  substitution rule.

Comment: Can you explain that more precisely, please?

Comment: Can you prove the result when $j(x)$ is a bounded, continuous, integrable function?

Comment: I guess I can prove it for simple functions...

Comment: No not really, I'm missing the case when the characteristic function has unbounded support.

Comment: Also it requires interchanging limits - not only with an integral...

Comment: You can always split the function into a bounded part plus a part where it's unbounded but has finite measure (it's integrable afterall).

Comment: Hmm I'm not getting it...

Comment: I freed the problem from assumptions and set the question from hint-required to proo-required. You can leave your answer here anyway. I won't bother, just wanted to let you know. Thanks anyway for your help!! :)

Comment: @AlexR. That won't necessarily work. Take $j=1/\sqrt{x}=f$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: The crucial fact is that $j \geq 0$ is positive. I would take a positive, increasing sequence of simple functions approximating $j$ and then pass the limit through with the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @AlexR. Sorry, you can get things to work with the MCT so I guess I'm just adding you really need $j \geq 0$.

Comment: @nayrb: Can you explain how, please? I mean don't you miss monotony here? *(Don't wonder I may free the setting but you can of course assume positivity.)*