# Semigroups: Entire Elements (II)

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, banach-spaces, lebesgue-integral

**Problem**

Given a Banach space $E$.

Consider a contraction C0-group:
$$T:\mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{B}(E):\quad\|T(t)x\|\leq\|x\|$$

Define its generator by:
$$Ax:=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}(T(h)x-x)\in E$$
*(It it is densely defined closed operator.)*

Denote the convergence radius by:
$$\rho_x:=\left(\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{\frac{1}{k!}\|A^kx\|}\right)^{-1}$$

Generate a group via Taylor series:
$$\rho_x=\infty:\quad e^{tA}x:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}t^kA^kx$$

Denote for shorthand:
$$x(t):=T(t)x$$

Introduce the smoothed elements:
$$x_n:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ne^{-(ns)^2}x(s)\mathrm{d}s$$

So the closure was all:
$$(x_n,e^{tA}x_n)\to(x,e^{tA}x)$$
How to prove this?

**Attempt**

The intgral exists since:
$$x\in\mathcal{C}(E):\quad\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ne^{-(ns)^2}\|x(s)\|\mathrm{d}s\leq\|x\|<\infty$$

Clearly it is an approximation:
$$x\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}):\quad x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ne^{-(ns)^2}x(s)\mathrm{d}s\to x(0)=x\quad(\|x\|_\infty=\|x\|<\infty)$$
*(See thread on: [Mollifiers: Approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1005745/79762))*

Moreover they are smooth since:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R})\cap\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}):\quad\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{h}\left(\varphi(\hat{s}-h)-\varphi(\hat{s})\right)x(\tfrac{1}{n}\hat{s})\mathrm{d}\hat{s}\to(-1)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi'(\hat{s})x(\tfrac{1}{n}\hat{s})\mathrm{d}\hat{s}$$
*(See thread on: [Mollifiers: Derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1097841/79762))*

But do the powers grow slow enough:
$$\|A^kx_n\|\leq\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\tfrac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}\hat{s}^k}e^{-\hat{s}^2}\right|\cdot\|x\|\mathrm{d}\hat{s}\leq\alpha a^n\|x\|$$

Also what about the closure:
$$\|e^{tA}x_m-e^{tA}x_n\|\leq\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{e^{-\hat{s}^2}}\|x(\tfrac{1}{m}\hat{s})-x(\tfrac{1}{n}\hat{s})\|\mathrm{d}\hat{s}\to0$$

That proves the assertion!

**Reference**

This is the close-up to: [Semigroups: Entire Vectors (I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1017300/79762)

It is taken from: Engel & Nagel, Exercise 3.12, Page 81

Comment: You need to explicit that $t\rightarrow T(t)x$ is continuous in $t$ as a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $X$ for each fixed $t$. That's the $C^{0}$ property. Otherwise what you wrote is not true.

Comment: Yes I implicitely assumed so. Btw I was also gonna ask you: What does the zero stand for in $\mathcal{C}_0$?

Comment: $C^{1}$ is continuously differentiable, $C^{2}$ is twice continuously differentiable. $C^{0}$ is continuous. You cannot implicitly assume $C^{0}$. It is an independent assumption, and critical for what you're doing.

Comment: So $\mathcal{C}_0$ means the same as $\mathcal{C}^0$? *(It's just so weird to write the regularity as subscript.)*

Comment: Yes, $C_{0}$ means that $t\mapsto T(t)x$ is $C^{0}$ for all $x$. The proper assumption is that it is continuous from the right at $t=0$, but it ends up implying continuity everywhere for a semigroup of bounded linear operators.

Comment: Ok, nice. :) Do you think it's worth it to open a new thread specially on that smoothness property claimed above in general setting with lebesgue-integral tag?

Comment: Ah so the zero actually stands for continuous in zero (from the right)? That makes sense as minimal requirement for the generator to exist.

Comment: $C_{0}$ semigroup specifically means $T(t)$ is a bounded linear operator for $t \ge 0$, $T(0)=I$, $T(s+t)=T(s)T(t)$ for $t, s \ge 0$ and $\lim_{h\downarrow 0}T(h)x=x$ for all $x \in X$. But $C_{0}$ ends up meaning $t\mapsto T(t)x$ is $C^{0}$ for all $x$.

Comment: Your definition of $e^{tA}$ is not an appropriate one.

Comment: @T.A.E.: What do you mean?

Comment: Actually, what do you mean? The point of semigroup theory is to define operators with an exponential property; one deliberately avoids an exponential series for an unbounded operator $A$ because it may not defined for anything except $0$.

Comment: Yes, for the general study of semigroup theory this here might be even useless. So one is even forced to avoid the approach by series. But for the study of thermodynamical states it is **extremely** practical to know that the entire elements establish a core for $\mathcal{C}_0$-groups. So that's why I'm doing this here.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Besides, do you have an example at hand where this happens for $\mathcal{C}_0$-semigroups? :)