# Mollifiers: Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

*This thread is meant as lemma for: [Semigroups & Generators: Entire Elements: Construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1097459/79762)*

Given a smooth mollifier: $\varphi\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}): \varphi'\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$

> Do the derivatives exist in the sense:
> $$f\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}):\quad\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{h}\left\{\varphi(\hat{x}+h)-\varphi(\hat{x})\right\}f(\tfrac{1}{n}\hat{x})\mathrm{d}\hat{x}\to\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi'(\hat{x})f(\tfrac{1}{n}\hat{x})\mathrm{d}\hat{x}\quad(\|f\|_\infty<\infty)$$
> *(Note the unbounded domain of integration.)*

Comment: Do you really need that every such $\phi$ satisfies this or are you just in the need of some $\phi$ with this property? The latter is rather easy to find.

Comment: @Thomas: Preferable for any such mollifier. Specifically for the Gaussian.

Comment: Hint: What is the value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\{\varphi(x+h)-\varphi(x)\}dx$?

Comment: Do you mean: $\int_a^b\varphi(x+h)-\varphi(x)\}\mathrm{d}x=\Phi(b+h)-\Phi(b)-\Phi(a+h)+ \Phi(a)$? But then I need to interchange some limits, don't I?

Comment: Hint: The value is 0!

Comment: @T.A.E.: Do you mean: $\lim_h\lim_c\frac{1}{h}\{\Phi(c+h)-\Phi(c)\}=\lim_h\frac{1}{h}0=0$?

Comment: I mean that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x+h)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x)dx$ for all $h$.

Comment: Ah that's also way the subtlty arises with the Gaussian integral that all derivatives vanish. Ok in fact it was then important explicitely involve a test function: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{h}\{\varphi(\hat{s}-h)-\varphi(\hat{s})\} f(\frac{1}{n}\hat{s})\mathrm{d}\hat{s}$

Comment: I don't think this is what you intended, but it's what you have in the statement of the problem. Did you mean to integrate $\varphi$ against another function?

Comment: @T.A.E.: Yes, I edited the problem.